# Azure design and connect

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Building a new MS AD domain on server 2019 for the office. Next to the MS AD domain we have Azure AD which is leading and where the tenant from office 365 is managed.

I would like to connect all my office users and their machines to the same Azure AD, implement SSO for some older applications and hardware.

- A. Can i sync from Azure AD to MSFT AD on-premises?
- B. Do i need AADDS in Azure?
- C. What kind of redundancy do i need to have when for example the Azure connection is failing?

Thanks,
#learningonthejob.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is one-way, from AD to Azure AD/Office 365. There are only few attributes that can be written back, and that's mostly for Hybrid configurations, and passwords if you have the corresponding feature (and licenses) enabled. There is no built-in functionality that syncs users from Azure AD to on-premises AD.  Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21411/aad-sync-to-local-ad.html) to get detailed information.

The Azure AD DS is a managed AD DS service in the cloud. In other words, if you want the traditional AD DS running in the cloud, you can take advantage of the Azure AD DS service by running AD DS under Azure AD. This means that you will be able to use traditional AD DS features, such as Kerberos and NTLM authentication, Group Policies (which aren’t supported in Azure AD), LDAP, etc.